# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x117540> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im gettin the  "Collection was mutates while beign enumerated" exception when my code is like this as follows:

```
NSString *poiStr = nil;
    int SuccessValue=0;
    NSMutableArray* poisArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mainMapView.annotations)
    {
        MKAnnotationView* anView = [mainMapView viewForAnnotation: annotation];
        if(anView)
        {

            POI* locationPOI = (POI*)[anView annotation];
            printf("\n Location poi shape groupId:%s=====%s",[locationPOI.shapeSpaceGroupId UTF8String],[poiStr UTF8String]);
            if((poiStr == nil) || ([poiStr isEqualToString:locationPOI.shapeSpaceGroupId]))
            {

                poiStr = locationPOI.shapeSpaceGroupId;
                [poisArray addObject:locationPOI];
                SuccessValue++;
            }
            printf("\n successValue:%d",SuccessValue);
            if(SuccessValue==2)
            {
                POI* poi=[poisArray objectAtIndex:0];
                [mainMapView removeAnnotation:poi];
                SuccessValue--;
            }

        }      

    }
```

Can anyone please suggest me what's the wrong in the code and how to solve the issues.

Thanks to all,
Madan.

Comment: You're modyfing while iterating. You can't do things like that. Comment out  [mainMapView removeAnnotation:poi]; and see if exception still is thrown

Comment: @Kamil please post that as an answer.

Comment: @Kamil:if I comment out the line  [mainMapView removeAnnotation:poi]; the exception is not generated but I need to remove the old annotion and use the new one.Can u tell me how to go with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically you are modifying the list in the loop you are iterating over it. The line that causes the problem is:

```
[mainMapView removeAnnotation:poi];
```

as you are iterating over mainMapView.annotations. A possible solution is to accumulate the elements you want to delete in a different list and remove them after the loop.

Based on your code, a possible solution would be:

```
     NSString *poiStr = nil;
    int SuccessValue=0;
    NSMutableArray* poisArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *to_delete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mainMapView.annotations)
    {
        MKAnnotationView* anView = [mainMapView viewForAnnotation: annotation];
        if(anView)
        {

            POI* locationPOI = (POI*)[anView annotation];
            printf("\n Location poi shape groupId:%s=====%s",[locationPOI.shapeSpaceGroupId UTF8String],[poiStr UTF8String]);
            if((poiStr == nil) || ([poiStr isEqualToString:locationPOI.shapeSpaceGroupId]))
            {

                poiStr = locationPOI.shapeSpaceGroupId;
                [poisArray addObject:locationPOI];
                SuccessValue++;
            }
            printf("\n successValue:%d",SuccessValue);
            if(SuccessValue==2)
            {
                POI* poi=[poisArray objectAtIndex:0];
                //[mainMapView removeAnnotation:poi];
                [to_delete addObject:poi];
                SuccessValue--;
            }

        }      

    }
    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in to_delete)
           [mainMapView removeAnnotation:poi];

    [to_delete release];
```

Comment: @Madan Mohan: The steps are 1. Create a new NSMutableArray before the loop, 2. instead of removing the annotation, add it to the new mutable array. 3. After the loop has finished iterate through your new mutable array and remove all the objects that are in it from the annotations.

Comment: Thanq very much you really saved my time..Its working fine as per your suggestion.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? I need to remove objects in between iterations of the for loop.

Comment: Put another loop outside it. Whenever you need to change the stuff inside, have it iterate the outer loop from start once more.